# Verify/correct my sentence: 虽然 我喜欢去露营, 我不没时间去最近 还有我没有有人去跟。

Tags: translation, writing-critique

I tested my simple translation skills and searched for an example English complex sentence on the internet...can someone judge my translation of this:

> Although I like to go camping, I haven't had time to go recently, and have nobody to go with.

to this:

> 虽然 我喜欢去露营, 我不没时间去最近 还有我没有有人去跟。

Corrections (grammar, word order, word choice) very much appreciated.

Comment: 虽然我喜欢露营，但最近我没时间去，也没有人可以一起去。 You can use http://lang-8.com/ to ask for correction of your translation.

Comment: I tried to sign up to the website but it said that no log ins are allowed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. When a sentence is started with a 虽然 (although), it is always followed by a "but" (但, 但是, 不过, 可是)
>
> 虽然 我喜欢去露营 **但**

~

> 2. Unlike in English, time is mentioned at the beginning of a clause,
>
> 虽然 我喜欢去露营 但 **最近**...

~

> 3. Most of the time, the subject 我 only need to be mentioned once in a sentence.
>
> 虽然 我喜欢去露营 但 最近

~

> 4. *我不没时间去* - '不没' is a 'double negative'- delete '不'
>
> 虽然 我喜欢去露营 但 最近 **没**时间去

~

> 5. 却  usually follows 但
>
> 虽然 我喜欢去露营 **但** 最近 **却**没时间去,

~

> 6. *还有我没有有人跟*。
>
>    - It is correct that 还有 means "also/ and" but in this case, use '也' make better connection between clauses in the sentence.
>    - omit 我
>    - 跟 (with) should follow by the subject and verb [go **with** me]=[**跟**我去]
>
> **也**没有人**跟我去**。

**Correct grammar**:

> "虽然 我喜欢去露营 但 最近 却没时间去, 也没有人跟我去。"

**Simplify**: (You only need the verb '去' once)(没有 can reduced to 没)

> "虽然 我喜欢露营 但 最近 却没时间, 也没人跟我去。"

Comment: Thank you very much, I still have a lot to learn as I'm sure you can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Although I like to go camping, 
尽管我很喜欢露营，
I haven't had time to go recently,
但是我最近都没有时间去，
and have nobody to go with
而且也没有人陪我。